# Neo4j query: How to build many labels into a label?

Tags: neo4j

My example gets my tweets and my friends's tweets:

```
MATCH 
 (me:User{user_id: "346"})-[:POSTS]->(t:Tweet), 
 (me)-[:FOLLOWS]->(following:User)-[:POSTS]->(t1:Tweet)
RETURN 
 t, t1
SKIP 10 LIMIT 10
```

Question: How can I merge t and t1 into a result set. Basically, I want to build json respond as below:

```
[
  {
    "tweet_id": "504597",
    "message": "Commodi consequatur qui libero.",
    "location": "25909 Hermann Village",
    "user": {
      "user_id": "346",
      "user_name": "Madaline.Mayer60346",
      "full_name": "Conor Hyatt",
      "avatar_url": "http://lorempixel.com/640/480"
    }
  },
  {
    "tweet_id": "504261",
    "message": "Atque hic ut velit.",
    "location": "42920 Esmeralda Lakes",
    "user": {
      "user_id": "347",
      "user_name": "Madaline",
      "full_name": "Conor Test",
      "avatar_url": "http://lorempixel.com/640/480"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to combine collections of tweets. How's this?

```
MATCH (me:User{user_id: "346"})-[:POSTS]->(t:Tweet)
WITH me, COLLECT(t) as myTweets
MATCH (me)-[:FOLLOWS]->(following:User)-[:POSTS]->(t:Tweet)
WITH myTweets + COLLECT(t) as allTweets
UNWIND allTweets as tweets
RETURN tweets
SKIP 10 LIMIT 10
```

It's usually a good idea to use ORDER BY when doing paging. Alternately you can forgo the UNWIND and take the relevant slide of the collection (RETURN tweets[10..20]), and if you need to order your collection of nodes by a property, there's an APOC Procedure for that [apoc.coll.sortNodes()](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_collection_functions)

EDIT:

You can try this query instead, whose MATCH should return tweets from both you and users you are following. However, SKIP and LIMIT, although they should work, likely won't return the result sets you want, as you aren't providing an ORDER BY clause currently (if you do supply this on your own, then you should also add an index on the property that you're ordering by).

```
MATCH (me:User{user_id: "346"})-[:POSTS|:FOLLOWS*1..2]->(t:Tweet)
RETURN t
SKIP 10 LIMIT 10
```

EDIT

Regarding your last question about the error when attempting to use APOC procedures, you can't use them like that, directly as part of a set operation.

Try this:

```
MATCH (t:Tweet{tweet_id: '1'}) 
CALL apoc.date.parseDefault(t.created_at, 'ms') YIELD value
SET t.created_milliseconds = value
RETURN t
```

Comment: Thank for your feedback. For the first thing, your updating code worked. But It too slow for respond data (My tweet sample database >3GB). Is there any other updating to improve performance?

Also, thank for APOC library

Comment: Try to substitute this line "MATCH (me:User{user_id: "346"})-[:POSTS]->(t:Tweet)" with this "MATCH (me:User{user_id: "346"}) with me MATCH (me)-[:POSTS]->(t:Tweet)"

Comment: It's very very fast if I only get my friend's tweets. (example: MATCH (me:User{user_id: "346"})-[:FOLLOWS]->(following:User)-[:POSTS]->(t:Tweet) RETURN t SKIP 1000 LIMIT 10). But I want to get tweets from both me and my friends.

Comment: I think you have limited options when it comes to returning both sets of tweets. You can't use UNION currently, because then you can't use SKIP and LIMIT on the unioned results (you can SKIP and LIMIT your tweets and your friends tweets separately, which should perform much better, but I don't think this is what you want). That leaves combining results into a collection, and taking the slice of the collection, or unwinding and then using SKIP and LIMIT.

Comment: I added an alternate query which can use a single MATCH to match on both your own tweets and tweets from followers.

Comment: Yes, InverseFalcon. Your updating sample code is good. That is what I need. Thank you so much!

Comment: ERROR: Invalid input 'p': expected 'n/N' (line 2, column 36 (offset: 66)) at this query, how can I fix this, thanks:


MATCH (t:Tweet{tweet_id: '1'})
SET t.created_milliseconds = CALL apoc.date.parseDefault(t.created_at,'ms')
RETURN t

Comment: The CALL for a procedure can't be done as part of the SET operation, it has to be done separately. I updated my answer with a query that should work and demonstrate usage.